# detect svn changes in a .bat

Tags: svn

I have a .bat and inside the .bat i would like to execute a special code if there's some modification inside the svn repository (for example, compile).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Win 2000 and later, this would assign the last output row from the svn status commmand to the svnOut variable and then test if the variable contains anything:

```
@echo off
set svnOut=
set svnDir=C:Your\path\to\svn\dir\to\check
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('svn status %svnDir%') do set svnOut=%%I

if "%svnOut%"==""  (
    echo No changes
) else (
    echo Changed files!
)
```

Why there is a line like this

```
set svnOut=
```

you have to figure out yourself. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's perfect, I'll test that ASAP.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work. For example, svn status returns some line with:
?    files
M    files2

that are local modification or files that are not in the repository.

I only want to have see "Changed files" when there s some repository changes.

Comment: I posted the answer with a modified version

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand what you want to do here... Do you want to perform a svn update, and if something has changed in the svn server repository, you want to perform a build with the new code? Or is it if something has been modified locally you want to rebuild?
If 1: What about conflicts?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the solution I found with the help of Tooony:

```
set vHEAD = 0
set vBASE = 0

set svnDir=<path to local svn directory>

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%I in ('svn info -r HEAD %svnDir%') do if "%%I"=="Revision:" set vHEAD=%%J
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%I in ('svn info -r BASE %svnDir%') do if "%%I"=="Revision:" set vBASE=%%J

if "%vBASE%"=="%vHEAD%"  (
    echo No changes
) else (
    echo Changed files!
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have your .bat execute `svnversion` (if you're using Subversion) or `SvnWCRev.exe` (if you're using TortoiseSVN) against the top-most level of your working copy.

Both output if your working copy has been modified.

`svnversion` appends a "M" to its output.
`SvnWCRev.exe` will print a line of text that the WC has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting this to be reactive? Or, on-demand?

For reactive, see [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1). The script will have to be named according to it's purpose: **pre-commit.bat**, **post-commit.bat**. The scripts are called as: **[script] [repos-path] [revision-number]**

For, on-demand:

- Working Copy

  - **svn log**
  - **svn st**
  - **svn diff**
  - **svn proplist**
- Repository

  - **svnlook author**
  - **svnlook changed**
  - **svnlook date**
  - **svnlook diff**
  - **svnlook history**

---

Example:

```
svn st "C:\path\to\working\directory\" >> C:\path\to\working\project.log
```

Every time you run the BAT, it'll add the **st** output to **project.log**. Adjust as needed.

Comment: It on demand.

I know the svn command (it s easy to find them eveyrwhere).

The question is to know how to use that in a .bat script

Comment: I don't want to put the status into a log file :)

I want the code of the .bat that do something like:

if(svn_changed())
  do this
else
  do that

Answer (score 0):

This version is based on @tooony's but checks the server for updates instead of the client.

```
@echo off
set svnOut=

rem Check svn server status of current working directory repository and see if first or second token is an *
for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ('svn status --show-updates') do if "%%I"=="*" set svnOut=%%I
rem echo "%svnOut%"

if "%svnOut%"==""  (
    echo No changes
) else (
    echo Changed files!
)
```